# Subscript text in a label, without slant?

Tags: plotting

Here is an example,

[image]

You can see that the the label is slanted. This is due to the subscript. Is there a way to obtain this label, *with the subscript*, but unslanted?

Comment: Can't test, so: try wrapping the string in `StandardForm[]`.

Comment: @J.M. That works, but now I cannot set the font of the label, which is important in a publication figure.

Comment: Then, try `StandardForm[Style[string, FontFamily -> "Times"]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, that works. What I tried before was `Style[StandardForm[string ...`, which ignores the style specification. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I was spitballing since I don't have a computer at the moment. :) Please write an answer yourself if indeed you got it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the [`FormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatType) to [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) seems like overkill. Instead, I would recommend modifying the [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics) option:

```
BarChart[{1}, ChartLabels->{Style[Subscript[A,x], SingleLetterItalics->False]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of @J.M., simply use `StandardForm[Style[string, FontFamily -> "Times"]]` in the label.